# Laravel - Fetch api, 302 and 405 error while ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fetch

I want to update my multiple records using fetch api. I have little Ajax class, I'm using this for my ajax call.

There is no error on console but, in network seems two failed call;

> 302 Found (it's about redirecting, I guess)
>
> 405 Method Not Allowed ()

Here is my ajax class

```
class Ajax {

...

async put(url, token, data) {

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
                "X-CSRF-Token": token
            },
            method: "put",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
        return response;
    }
}
```

My event;

```
document.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change',function () {
     let ids = [],

     token = document.head.querySelector('[name=csrf-token]').content;
       console.log(this.value);
     document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(function (box) {    if(box.hasAttribute('checked')) {
            ids.push(box.value)
    }
  });
    if (this.value == 1) {
          let ajax = new Ajax();
          ajax.put('comments/approve',token,ids)
          .then(data => console.log(data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
   }
});
```

and my route; (its under to the "admin/comments" prefix)

```
Route::put('approve',['as'=>'comments.approve','uses'=>'CommentController@approveComment']);
```

Comment: Laravel uses a method called method spoofing.  Try to use a POST request instead and send a parameter in the payload called "_method" with value PUT

Comment: Also the route should be /admin/comments/aproove if I'm not wrong

Comment: as I said I have prefix for it

Comment: but post is working. I don't get it, why post working instead put ? I'm not just sending data also I'm updating it.